# Fetching the data from database to Radio Button with right format

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Good day.

**This is illustration i want to be output to my blade page.**

```
1. What was your dining experience?

Dine-in

Carry out

Delivery

2. How did you order?

Hotline

Online/Website

In-person
```

However I don't know where should i adjust, In my **php** or to my **Mysql**

**In My Controller:**

```
 public function getsurveyquestion()
{

  $questionstitle = DB::select('SELECT q_type,q_title FROM survey_question');

  $questions = DB::select('SELECT q_type,q_title,qcategory_question as category FROM survey_question as sq LEFT JOIN 
  (SELECT id,qid,qcategory_question FROM survey_category_question) scq ON sq.id = scq.qid');

  return view('/survey')
  ->with('question',$questions)
  ->with('questiontitle',$questionstitle);
}
```

**In my Blade Page:**

```
@foreach($questiontitle as $questions)

  <b style="font-weight:300;"">{{$questions->q_title}}<br><br></b>

  @foreach($question as $test)
    {{$test->category}}<br><br>

  @endforeach

@endforeach
```

**This is my output to my blade page, which is wrong.**
[image]
**My Query output:**
[image: myqueryoutput]

Comment: I don't understand, what is your expected output exactly?

Comment: at my first illustration at the top . I want my output look like that.

Comment: So you want to separate the category?

Comment: @Grayback read my first sentence I want to look my output look like this:

Comment: @Grayback i will add more information

Comment: @Grayback ok now..

Comment: Your DB is wrong, put the category in another table and every row has its category. This will simplify the approach of your database

Comment: @Grayback what do you mean for that put the category in another table and every row has its category?

Comment: the id of category is in the question??

Answer (score 1):

modify in your Blade Page:

```
@foreach($questiontitle as $questions)
  <b style="font-weight:300;"">{{$questions->q_title}}<br><br></b>
    @foreach($question as $test)
       @if($questions->q_title == $test->q_title) {{-- add condition here --}}
          {{$test->category}}<br><br>
       @endif
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```